# How to make Hibernate see the changes in DB and synchronize with the runtime object instances

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions, struts

Firstly clarify that I checked a lot of posts before posting. Maybe I just can't understand but the solution was posted.

I am developing an struts app v 1.2.9 with hibernate 3 (no spring).
My problem is that if for example I delete an entity, I do commit, then I can see the changes are ok in the database. But, if I query the table, retrieve this entity that I delete in advance.

This is part of my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">X</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">X</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider

My HibernateUtil (copied from other posts)

```
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

      import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

      public class HibernateUtil {

            private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

            static {
                try {
                    // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                sessionFactory = new           Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
                }
            }

            public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
                return sessionFactory;
            }
```

And my DAO

```
import com.mylib.modelo.Television;
import com.mylib.plugins.HibernateUtil;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.mylib.plugins.HibernateUtil;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;


public class TelevisionsDAO  {

   private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TelevisionsDAO.class);

    public Television getTelevisionById(int idTelevision){
        Session session=null;
        Transaction tx =null;
        Television rs =null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.flush();

            //QJ: Use Hibernate Criteria for more secured functionalities
            rs=(Television) session.createCriteria(Television.class)
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("idTelevision", idTelevision))
                     .uniqueResult();
            if(rs!=null)session.refresh(rs);
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return rs;
    }
    public List<Television> encuentraTelevisions(Integer idUsuario){
        Session session=null;
        Transaction tx =null;
        List rs =null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            //QJ: Use Hibernate Criteria for more secured functionalities
            rs=(List)session.createCriteria(Television.class)
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("usuario.idUsuario", idUsuario))
                     .list();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return rs;
    }

    public List<Television> encuentraTelevisions(Integer idUsuario, Boolean buscaOfrece){
        Session session=null;
        Transaction tx =null;
        List rs =null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            //QJ: Use Hibernate Criteria for more secured functionalities
            rs=(List)session.createCriteria(Television.class)
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("usuario.idUsuario", idUsuario))
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("buscaOfrece", buscaOfrece))
                     .list();
//            for(int i=0;i<rs.size();i++){
//                session.refresh((Television)rs.get(i));
//            }
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return rs;
    }

    public boolean hasTelevision(Integer idUsuario, Boolean buscaOfrece,
            Integer idConocimiento){
        Session session=null;
        Transaction tx =null;
        List rs =null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            //session.flush();
            //QJ: Use Hibernate Criteria for more secured functionalities
            rs=(List)session.createCriteria(Television.class)
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("usuario.idUsuario", idUsuario))
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("buscaOfrece", buscaOfrece))
                     .add(Restrictions.eq("conocimiento.idConocimiento", idConocimiento))
                     .list();
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return rs.size()>0;
    }

    public Integer addTelevision(Television television) throws Exception {
        log.info("addTelevision");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Integer p = (Integer) session.save(television);
            session.flush();
            session.refresh(television);
            tx.commit();

            log.info("end addTelevision");
            return p;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.error("addTelevision", e);
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void quitarTelevision(Television television) throws Exception {
        log.info("quitarTelevision");

        Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.delete(television);
            session.flush();
            //session.refresh(television);
            tx.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.error("quitarTelevision", e);
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        } 
    }
```

In TelevisionBL:

public Integer addTelevision(Usuario usuario, Integer idConocimiento,
        boolean buscaOfrece)throws Exception{

```
    //compruebo que el usuario no contiene la telerencia en cuestión       
    if(!televisionDAO.hasTelevision(
            usuario.getIdUsuario(), buscaOfrece, idConocimiento)){
        Television tel = new Television();
        tel.setBuscaOfrece(buscaOfrece);
        tel.setUsuario(usuario);
        tel.setConocimiento(new Conocimiento(idConocimiento));
        return telerenciasDAO.addTelevision(tel);
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
  }

   public boolean quitarTelevisionSafe(Integer idTelevision, Integer idUsuarioRequesting) throws Exception{
        Television television = televisionsDAO.getTelevisionById(idTelevision.intValue());
        if( television.getUsuario().getIdUsuario().intValue() == idUsuarioRequesting.intValue() ){
            televisionsDAO.quitarTelevision(television);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is a tad lacking in information.  Is this in two different sessions?  If so, did you read the object in one session before deleting it in the other?  You also have not shown us the actual code driving this.  You are going to be better off with a simplified example.  Take the calls from the DAO and inline them into the code driving this.  Makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks Steve! First, maybe I am confused, but I read that HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); opens a new session when needed, or uses a existing one if it already exists. Second, what I have is: - From the Action, I call to a BL method that only instanciate a new TelevisionDAO and calls televisionsDAO.encuentraTelevisions(idUsuario, Boolean.TRUE) and I return the results to my jsp via Json; After this, from another action, I call the "addTelevision" method in the BL (see in the main post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you need to close the session.

Comment: I tried, but, It throws Exception. Here the code I tried:

  public void quitarTelevision(Television television) throws Exception {
        log.info("quitar");
 
            session.delete(television);
            session.flush();
            //session.refresh(television);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            log.error("quitarTelevision", e);
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }

Comment: What is the Exception being thrown?

Comment: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Comment: One of your other mehods may be the reason.  Close the session when done in every one of them.  The transaction may have already been comitted elsewhere thereby causing this error.

Comment: I have added finally{
            session.close();
        } 
on each method, and I have made a junit test. It is giving me Session was already closed
exception in the first method

Answer (score 0):

Taking account of the idea that I didn't really now if the session was or not open (with getCurrentSession()) and when it was closed, because session close doesn't work, although I read in some articles that it was recommended to not open every time the session, I decided to have the control on it and I changed all my DAO methods to open and close session every time with

```
Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

and, in the finally block,

```
session.close();
```

I would like to do a more efficient code, but if like that is working, I can live with it. Next time, I would integrate Spring MVC in my app that helps with the control of the transactionality.

Thanks a lot to Todd & Steve.